# GooglePlayServices not working after ActionBarSherlock imported

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

**ANSWERED:** Delete support library inside of libs inside of class.

I have been struggling to get ActionBarSherlock library working in my Android App where I have a Google Map fragment.

My app was fully functional showing maps and once I (for the first time) successfully imported the actionbarsherlock library(that is in the list of projects open in package explorer) all lines of codes related to google maps is causing an error : the import of com.google.android.gms can not be resolved.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity  {

    private GoogleMap googleMap = null;
    SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
```

I have tried to re-import google play services_lib (which is ALSO on the left side in package explorer) and nothing has changed. I tried restarting eclipse but that did not help. I suppose the first step is to check if google play services lib is in my project but I do not know how to do that.

Is there some kind of issue of having both of these(maps and actionbarsherlock?).

**UPDATE:** this began happening IMMEDIATELY after the errors went away from actionbarsherlock. 
Also as written below: under Android dependencies, both jar files are there, (google-play-services_lib.jar and actionbarsherlock.jar). Also, yes google play services is referenced there

I just tried going back to simply FragmentActivity and switching imports from import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity; to import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; and it continues to say that it can't be resolved

**UPDATE2:** When I have the code as

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
```

(with the correct import) it says that FragmentActivity can not be resolved to a type, but when it is

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity  {
```

it says that the hierarchy of MainActivity is inconsistent

**UPDATE 3:**

```
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-07-08 13:40:04 - Maps] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-07-08 13:40:04 - Maps] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-07-08 13:40:04 - Maps] Versions found are:
[2013-07-08 13:40:04 - Maps] Path: D:\Workspace\google-play-services_lib\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-07-08 13:40:04 - Maps]    Length: 484258
[2013-07-08 13:40:04 - Maps]    SHA-1: bd6479f5dd592790607e0504e66e0f31c2b4d308
[2013-07-08 13:40:04 - Maps] Path: D:\Workspace\actionbarsherlock2\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-071a61c\actionbarsherlock\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-07-08 13:40:04 - Maps]    Length: 271754
[2013-07-08 13:40:04 - Maps]    SHA-1: 53307dc2bd2b69fd5533458ee11885f55807de4b
[2013-07-08 13:40:04 - Maps] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that you have referenced ABS in your project and that you have the ABS version of the v4 support lib (this is in the ABS libs folder) in your project (a more recent version of the V4 support lib is also acceptable).

Note that after adding the ABS version of the support library into your project you may then see errors like this on your logcat:

jar mismatch ...SHA1 check ...

This means that you are trying to use different versions of the V4 support libraries. Once you have the ABS version in your project you can delete any other versions of the support library from your referenced projects.

Comment: android-support v4, yes. what is this reference?

Comment: Did you notice that even though I am trying to help you, I used the word PLEASE? Please would you clarify your comment - I don't understand it

Comment: Sorry! I quickly wrote that comment. I was asking what reference you are talking about(it was confusing before your edit). How do i figure out what version of support lib i have?

Comment: Hey, so could you take a look at update 3? I believe this is what you are talking about but I don't know how to fix it even with your suggestion

Comment: Also, as I briefly mentioned in the question, I have been trying this a lot so I have actionbarsherlock 1, actionbarsherlock 2 and actionbarsherlock so I am not sure which I am using and I am especially not sure that it is actionbarsherlock 2. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated here as I am lost

Comment: DONE: You were 100% correct! I needed to simply delete the support library inside of my libs folder. I had read this elsewhere but it didn't click. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

ADD google-play-services.jar to the Referenced Libraires in Package Explorer and also check Project Properties -> Java Build path and see Libraries tab contain the google-play-services.jar..

Comment: under Android dependencies, both jar files are there, (google-play-services_lib.jar and actionbarsherlock.jar).

Also, yes google play services is referenced there

Comment: with the latest ADT there is some problem with google-play-services.. In eclipse move your cursor on to the error and say fix project setup.